# graph database physical distribution and indexing

Tags: database, graph, representation

My question is not on the query language but on the physical distribution of data in a graph database.

---

Let's assume a simple user/friendship model. In RDBs you would create a table storing `IDUserA`/`IDUserB` for a representation of a friendship.

If we assume a bunch of IT-Girls for example with the Facebook limit of 5k friends, we quickly get to huge amounts of data. If `GirlA(ID 1)` simply likes `GirlB(ID 2)`. It would be an entry wir [1][2] in the table.

With this model it is not possible to get over data redundancy in friendship, because then we have to do either two queries (is there an entry in `IDUserA` or an entry in `IDUserB` with `ID = 1`, what means physically searching both columns) or to store `[1][2]` and `[2][1]`, what ends up in data redundancy. For a heavy user this means checks against 5000/10000 entries containing an indexed column, which is astronomically big.

---

So ok, use GraphDBs. We assume the `Girls` as Nodes. `GirlA` is the first one ever entered into the DB, so her ID is simply 0. The Entry contains a `isUsed` - flag for the data chunk of a byte, and is 1 if it is in use. The next 4 bytes are a flag for the filename where her node is stored in (what leads to nearly 4.3 Billion possible files and we assume the file size of 16.7MB so we could use 3 more bytes to declare the offset inside.

Lets assume we define the `username` datatype as a chunk of 256 (and be for the example so ridgid).

```
For GirlA it is [1]0.0.0.0-0.0.0
= Her User ID 0 times 256 = 0
For GirlB it is [1]0.0.0.0-0.1.0
= Her User ID 1 times 256 = 256,
```

so her `Usernamedata` starts on file 0_0_0_0.dat on offset 256 from start. We don't have to search for her data, we could simply calculate them. A User 100 would be stored in the same file on offset 25600 and so forth and so on. User 65537 would be stored in file 0_0_0_1.dat on offset 0. Loaded in RAM this is only a pointer and pretty fast.

So we could store with this method more nodes than humans ever lived.
BUT: How to find relationships? Ok, with edges. But how to store them? All in one "column" is stupid, because then we are back on relationship models. In a hashtable? Ok, we could store the 0_0_0_0.frds as a hashtable containing all friends of User0, kick off a new instance of a User-Class Object, add the Friends to a binary list or tree that could be found by the pointer cUser.pFriendlist and we would be done. But I think that I make a mistake.

Shouldn't GraphDatabases be something different than mathematical nodes connected with hash tables filled with edges?

The use of nodes and edges is clear, because it allows to connect everything with relationships of anything. But whats about the queries and their speed?

Keeping different edges in different type of files seems somekind of wrong, even if the accessibility is really fast on SSDs.

Sure, I could use a simple relational table to store a edgetype/dataending pair, but please help me: where do I get it wrong!

Comment: It breaks all down a "isn't that a little bit to "flat document database" for a graphical database and "what speaks against this solution". :)

Comment: To specify it a bit more: How to find edges (best practice) in a huge bulk of edges! (Physically, not in cypher-code)